# Как отобразить RecyclerView плиткой по два элемента?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

Есть список объектов, отображаемый ресайклером. Выводится он элемент за элементом в столбик.
Я же хотел бы сделать так, что бы список отображался по два элемента в столбик. Пример на скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю, стоит ли код адаптера сюда прикреплять, так как он шаблонный. Но вот, написано грязновато, потом рефакторить буду.

````
class RecyclerViewAdapter(context: Context,
                          var imageList: ArrayList<ImageObject>,
                          private val onImageClickListener: OnImageClickListener) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

    interface OnImageClickListener {
        fun onWorkClick(workData: ImageObject, position: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_images_view, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val imageObject: ImageObject = imageList[position]

        holder.bind(imageObject, holder, onImageClickListener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return imageList.size
    }

    class ViewHolder constructor(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        private val thumbnail: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail)

        fun bind(imageObject: ImageObject, holder: ViewHolder, onImageClickListener: OnImageClickListener) {

            //Glide.with(itemView).load("SOME URL").into(thumbnail)

            Glide.with(itemView).load(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(thumbnail);


            /*holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener {
                //onImageClickListener.onWorkClick(workData, adapterPosition)

*/

        }
    }

}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не помешал бы код того места где лежит данный виджет. Но вообще нужно сетить определенного типа LayoutManager:

```
rvList.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
```

где `2` это кол-во колонок. Это необходимо сделать перед привязки адаптера к списку. [Вот здесь](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-grid-layout#0) можно более подробно посмотреть, а здесь [туториал](https://www.android4dev.com/how-to-use-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-android/) есть.